# Tkinter tk.Scrollbar Grid and alignment issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I created a Text field in Tkinter, new items added next to the text field and I can't get the bottom line with grid. window does not open when grid is added. What is the solution?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk

pencere = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(pencere)
frame.pack()

scrol = tk.Scrollbar(frame)
scrol.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

text = "Good bye"

text = tk.Text(frame,width=70, height=0)
text.insert(tk.INSERT, text)
text.config(yscrollcommand=scrol.set)
scrol.config(command=text.yview)
text.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)

buton = tk.Button(frame, text='close', command=pencere.destroy)
buton.pack()

text.grid(row=1, column=1)

pencere.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear Zolo Baba the bar cannot appear because you are still using "pack" and "grid" together. Because of the reasons that I mentioned above, we can use only one layout management method for the master. I edited your code with using only "grid" method.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk

pencere = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(pencere)
frame.grid()

scrol = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient = tk.VERTICAL)
text = tk.Text(frame,width=70, height=5)

text.insert(tk.INSERT, "###\n\n\nNote\n\n\n###")
text.config(yscrollcommand=scrol.set)
text.grid(sticky="W")

scrol.config(command=text.yview)
scrol.grid(row = 0, column=2, sticky="NS")

buton = tk.Button(frame, text='close', command=pencere.destroy)
buton.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

pencere.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use **pack** and **grid** methods for the widgets which have the same master. In this example, your frame, text and scrol are already adjusted by **pack** therefore tkinter does not allow to adjust text or an another element with **grid** as long as you don't create another frame for the element that you want to adjust with **grid**.

So, in my opinion there are two options:

1. If you still want to use **grid**, you should adjust whole widgets(frame, text etc.) with grid.

   2. If you want to use **grid** but you don't want to change widgets which are alredy adjusted by pack, create a new frame for your text.